# Cacti graphs showing empty data though rrd files are getting generated

Tags: cacti

1. rrd files are getting generated through cron job.
2. I have not configured snmp and i configured the same in graph management.

So, there is no need to configure snmp on unix server (localhost).

Comment: It usually takes a while for it to collect data that it can use to generate graphs. If you set it up today, give it time

Comment: Yes .. It took almost a day. It is working now

Comment: You could vote for my answer so that anyone who finds this question from search engines gives their cacti installation time to collate data before it can show them graphs.

Answer (score 1):

It usually takes a while for it to collect data that it can use to generate graphs. If you set it up today, give it time for it to collate data it can use to show graphs.